# Bootstrap not working on simple html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html markup currently just displaying simple text "HELLO STACKOVERFLOW" with some styling. The markup was taken from illustrator and I am trying to incorporate bootstrap to make a more responsive page. I cannot figure out why the text will not change with the browser size. It seems fixed. The browser shows the bootstrap scripts are working but I can't figure out what is overriding bootstrap. The style in the code are just text size and color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1190,height=792" />
    <title>5707.CC2014.R30TEST2-1</title>
    <link href="css/idGeneratedStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="script/idGeneratedScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body id="x5707.CC2014.R30TEST2-1" onload="RegisterInteractiveHandlers();" lang="en-GB" xml:lang="en-GB" style="width:1190px;height:792px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="width:13883.54px;height:2339.22px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; -webkit-transform: translate(0px,45.2px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.05);transform-origin: 0% 0%; transform: translate(0px,45.2px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.05);">
                <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1"><span id="_idTextSpan000" class="CharOverride-1" style="position:absolute;top:-470.32px;left:0px;letter-spacing:15.4px;">HELLO STACKOVERFLOW</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What makes you think that resizing text based on window size is a feature of Bootstrap?

Comment: The inline styles (particularly width) on both `body` and `div.col-lg-6` are probably causing some issues.

Comment: I think is because you are setting the width and the height of the col-lg-6

Comment: Yes, if you want to go down the road of responsiveness, you need to forget about setting fixed widths like you are on your `col-lg-6` div.

Comment: @Quentin Not necessarily resizing the text but the text should adapt to screen size on a smaller browser window.

Comment: @bos570... adapt how? You don't mean you're expecting the font size to change are you? If so you need to be using `vw`.

Comment: @bos570 — Oh. So you are asking why the element that you explicitly said should be `width:13883.54px` is as wide as you said it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two comments are just right. You got this code from a generator (Illustrator as you wrote above, though style stylesheets are InDesign stylesheets). Generators often add inline styling. That's what happened here, too. Just delete all the `style="[css-rules]"` attributes from your body elements and it will be working.

Answer (score 1):

See the rules for [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) and [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

The sizes set by Bootstrap's stylesheet using the `.col-lg-6` has a specificity of `0010` while the sizes set by Illustrator's `style` *attribute* have a specificity of `1000`.

The style attribute is more specific, so it overrides the CSS rather than the other way around.